# IntoDNS SOA Retry Record

Tags: soa-record

I can't reach my website.
When I check into DNS, it gives me this error:

```
Your SOA RETRY value is: 10800. That is NOT OK
```

Can anyone help me about this please?

Answer (score 0):

The value for RETRY must be less than the value for REFRESH. You have probably set REFRESH to a value that is too small.